# The cost of locking

Tags: c#, multithreading, locking

I have a cache (which is used by a web application) which internally uses two caches - one short term cache, which is just used within a request, and a long term cache which is used "permanently" (across requests).

I have the following code, note that all underlying data-structures are thread safe.

```
public TCache Get(CacheDependency cachdeDependancy, Func<CacheDependency, TCache> cacheItemCreatorFunc)
{
    TCache cacheItem;
    if (shortTermCache.TryGetValue(cachdeDependancy.Id, out cacheItem))
    {
        return cacheItem;
    }

    DateTime cacheDependancyLastModified;
    if (longTermCache.TryGetValue(cachdeDependancy.Id, out cacheItem)
        && IsValid(cachdeDependancy, cacheItem, out cacheDependancyLastModified))
    {
        cacheItem.CacheTime = cacheDependancyLastModified;
        shortTermCache[cachdeDependancy.Id] = cacheItem;
        return cacheItem;
    }

    cacheItem = cacheItemCreatorFunc(cachdeDependancy);

    longTermCache.Add(cachdeDependancy.Id, cacheItem);
    shortTermCache[cachdeDependancy.Id] = cacheItem;
    return cacheItem;
}
```

Obviously it's still possible (probably even likely) that the code above won't be consistent when running concurrent (i.e. multiple web requests).
However I wrote some unit-tests and what I saw is that never an "exception" occurs. What can happen is that the same item is added again even though it's already there etc. --> I think you can see what I mean when you look at the code.

Still I thought it would be nice to have a solution which always works correct and is consistent.

So I rewrote this code using a simple double-checking lock mechanism (maybe this could even be better, by adding another/second lock for the other cache?):

```
public TCache Get(CacheDependency cachdeDependancy, Func<CacheDependency, TCache> cacheItemCreatorFunc)
{
    TCache cacheItem;
    if (shortTermCache.TryGetValue(cachdeDependancy.Id, out cacheItem))
    {
        return cacheItem;
    }

    lock (_lockObj)
    {
        if (shortTermCache.TryGetValue(cachdeDependancy.Id, out cacheItem))
        {
            return cacheItem;
        }

        DateTime cacheDependancyLastModified;
        if (longTermCache.TryGetValue(cachdeDependancy.Id, out cacheItem)
            && IsValid(cachdeDependancy, cacheItem, out cacheDependancyLastModified))
        {
            cacheItem.CacheTime = cacheDependancyLastModified;
            shortTermCache[cachdeDependancy.Id] = cacheItem;
            return cacheItem;
        }

        cacheItem = cacheItemCreatorFunc(cachdeDependancy);

        longTermCache.Add(cachdeDependancy.Id, cacheItem);
        shortTermCache[cachdeDependancy.Id] = cacheItem;
        return cacheItem;
    }
}
```

I think this code now works correctly in multi-thread environments.

However what I'm not sure is:
Will this not be terribly slow and therefore also kind of destroys the purpose of the cache? Would it maybe be better to live with the problem, that the cache can sometimes have an "inconsistent" behavior?
Because if there are 1000 web requests at the same time, all have to wait until they can enter the lock zone. Or is this not really a problem at all, because a CPU only has a specific amount of cores (and therefore "real" parallel threads) at once and this performance penalty will always be minor?

Comment: It depends a lot on 2 thinks: how many cuncurrent threads access your code, and how long it takes to run the code within the lock statement.
As long as it access only memory (no db, no disk) and the methods you call are quick, it should not be a real problem. (if your 1000th request need to wait a millisecond or so, it's not going to be a bottleneck)
But again, it dipends on the real scenario.

Comment: You can use [Amdahls law](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amdahlsches_Gesetz) to calculate the improvement by parallelization.

Comment: There can only be one cache item be created at the same time which seems like a killer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use a `ConcurrentDictionary`, you already have a way to do what you want - you can simply use the `GetOrAdd` method:

```
shortTermCache[cacheDependency.Id] = 
  longTermCache.GetOrAdd(cacheDependency.Id, _ => cacheItemCreatorFunc(cachdeDependancy));
```

Quick and easy :)

You can even expand this to include the short term cache check:

```
return
  shortTermCache.GetOrAdd
  (
    cacheDependency.Id,
    _ =>
    {
      return longTermCache
             .GetOrAdd(cacheDependency.Id, __ => cacheItemCreatorFunc(cacheDependency));
    }
  );
```

Though it's kind of unnecessary to use a `ConcurrentDictionary` for a per-request cache - it doesn't really have to be thread-safe.

As for your original code, yes, it is broken. The fact that you don't see that during your testing isn't too surprising - multi-threading issues are often hard to reproduce. That's why you want to code to be *correct*, first and foremost - and that means you have to understand what exactly is going on, and what kind of concurrency issues can possibly happen. In your case, there's two shared references: `longTermCache` and the `cacheItem` itself. Even if all the objects you're working with are thread-safe, you've got no guarantee that *your* code is thread-safe as well - in your case, there might possibly be a contention over `cacheItem` (how thread-safe is that?), or someone might have added the same cache item in the meantime.

How exactly this breaks depends heavily on the actual implementations - for example, `Add` might throw an exception if an item with the same Id is already present, or it might not. Your code might expect all of the cache items to be the same reference, or it might not. `cacheItemCreatorFunc` might have horrible side-effects or be expensive to run, or it might not.

Your update with the added `lock` does fix those issues. However, it doesn't handle the way you're leaking `cacheItem` all over the place, for example. Unless `cacheItem` is perfectly thread-safe as well, you could encounter some hard to track bugs. And we already know it isn't immutable either - at the very least, you're changing the cache time.

Comment: thanks for the answer. Tbh I already use only a Dictinoary for the ShortTermCache - I just wante d to prevent discussions, about using "thread safe data structures" every where ;)  What I really would also be interested in (if it's even possible to make a statement) how much you think the whole "locking" thing would make a difference performance wise.

Comment: @OschtärEi That isn't really question that can't be answered in general. It might very well be there will be zero impact - or it might bring your whole application to a halt. Why do you even maintain the request-local cache?

Comment: I thought so... well the `IsStillValid` method takes a little time to complete - so I only want do to this once in a request and then use the short term cache for further accesses.